# c# How do I allow the same user to login multiple times, but limit it to a certain number

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I have a project I'm working on.  The user registers, which creates an entry in a MySQL table with their details.  The user can then purchase a 1, 5, 10 or unlimited subscription.  The number being the amount of simultaneous logins allowed. (IE the amount of concurrent instances of the app over multiple machines)

I have looked at Singleton, Multiton and Mutex, all of which I'm not sure on how to get it to work in my situation.

My Idea:
I was thinking of some form of heartbeat to the MySQL server updating a Date time cell along with the session ID, then if someone else tries to login, it checks how new the datetime is, if its too old, allow login, if its too new give the option to login anyway and close the other session.

Comment: This is neither a SQL or C# question.  It's a design question.  How do you define "concurrent"?  When the app is running?  When the database is accessed?  What kind of usage patterns are there?  When would you check (login/logout?)  What if the app or machine crashes?  Do you still count that as logged on?  Is it per user or per machine?

Answer (score 0):

A database-driven solution is probably the best way to do this.

On connection, you could return a session ID. Then, every n minutes, send another heartbeat, which refreshes the lastSeen time for the session. Make sure, however, that you verify network connectivity because otherwise someone can just turn their wifi off and boom, as many as they want. (of course, that doesn't matter if your app relies on the network!)

You'll also need to make sure the heartbeat returns whether the session is still valid.